# Why don't games use expression templates for math?

Tags: c++, templates, optimization, game-engine, expression-templates

I can imagine expression templates doing awful things to compile times for things as pervasive as vectors/matrices/quaternions etc, but if it is such a great speed boost why don't games use it?  It's quite obvious that SIMD instructions can exploit data level parallelism to great effect.  Expression templates and lazy evaluation together seem to make sense, at least when it comes to eliminating temporaries.

So while libraries like Eigen advertise such features, I don't see this done commonly in middleware (e.g. Havok) or games where things are extremely speed critical.  Can anyone shed some light on this?  Does it have to do with non-determinism or branch prediction?

Comment: What does SIMD have to do with anything? I don't see the connection there

Comment: SIMD instructions have nothing to do with expression templates, nor does lazy evaluation. It has nothing to do with non-determinism or branch prediction either. Not one of those four things have *anything* to do with expression templates.

Answer (score 6):

I can think of a lot of reasons:

- it hurts compile-times. Longer compile-times means that testing any change you made to the code takes longer. It hurts productivity.
- it's complex. Most likely, many developers on the team are not familiar with expression templates, and will have a hard time reading and debugging them.
- Games often have to work on multiple platforms, with various compilers which may have a wide range of shortcomings, which might for example make advanced template trickery problematic.
- It's generally not necessary. You can write efficient code without expression templates. It just gets more verbose, and you have to do more hand-holding for the compiler.
- Game developers are extremely skeptical of anything that wasn't already used in games 10 years ago. It's not long ago that several major developers stuck to C: not because C++ wasn't good enough, but because it was "new". Game developers are conservative as hell.

And of course, the obvious question: *where* would they use expression templates? Is there enough *complex* math to really make it worthwhile? Games tend to rely on a fairly small number of linear algebra operations, which will typically be heavily hand-tuned in any case.

Comment: 10 years may be a bit much, they're getting a lot better; most major releases this year were built with MSVC 2005. :P

Comment: I'm not just talking about compiler versions though, but also choice of language and language features. It's possible to use a modern C++ compiler to write C or something that amounts to little more than C with classes.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add one more reason not stated in the above answers. Apologies if it is and I missed it.

Adding templates to math based classes, such as a vec3 class, can change the meaning of operators and lead to functions that are invalid for some template types.

Take for instance,

```
vec3<int> myVec( 3, 5, 4 );
myVec.Normalize();
```

What would normalize mean to an integer vector? All of the sudden when we add templates to math constructs, we invalidate many existing functions, such as the example described above.

Also, another thing worth mentioning is that many math constructs are optimized with certain types because optimization is so important in games. GPU's are floating point calculating machines. Doubles take up double the space of floats and are quite a bit slower to compute with, even though it may seem like an obvious use case to a new game developer.

I hope this example makes sense. Templates are a great tool but math constructs in games are just not the right place to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the parts of a game that are both performance sensitive and math heavy and still tend to run on the CPU rather than the GPU are applying the same basic operations to large numbers of elements. Some examples are animation blending, physics calculations, visibility tests, etc.

The best approach to optimizing these sorts of problems on current console hardware is generally to try and batch as much work together as possible and to aim for maximum data locality to avoid expensive cache misses. The actual math can then be optimized using SIMD intrinsics and will typically be carefully hand optimized. The kind of optimizations that expression templates give you can be performed relatively easily during that hand optimization phase but there are various other important optimizations that are also likely to be performed that expression templates won't give you. Often this critical code will have sections with custom optimizations for each target platform and won't be very portable.

I think the reason that expression templates aren't widely used is that they add software complexity (for all the reasons described by jalf) to non performance critical code that doesn't really warrant it while not covering all the optimizations that are necessary for the really performance critical code that shows up at the top of profiles.

Comment: This is for the most part true but is changing with compute shaders and OpenCL. Many physics calculations, especially deferred requests utilize the GPU's superior floating point computation.